# Rename columns in a dataframe based on vector of names (character vector)

Tags: r

I'm pretty new to using R and I'm sure there is a simple solution to this problem but I am pulling my hair out with this.

I'm reading in a fixed width file (fwf) that has no column names.  I have most of the column names as a field in a separate delimited file.  I'm trying to assign the column names from the delimited file to the fwf.

I've imported the column names saved to a character vector called `VNames` ( e.g. chr [1:225] "NameAAA" "NameAAB" NameAAC"...) I'd like to apply the names as part of the `read.fwf`

```
CombMatrix <- read.fwf(
   file = fixedFileName,
   width = c(32, 3, 5, 15, rep(1, 225)),
   col.names = ("ID", "Gender", "Score", "Department", VNames),
   na.string = "",
   fill = TRUE,
   strip.white = TRUE)
```

I keep getting an error

> Error:
>
> unexpected ',' in: "  width=c(32,3,5,15,rep(1, 225)),   col.names =
>   ("ID","

Thank you in advance with any help on this!

Comment: You forgot to add function `c`, try `col.names = c("ID", ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are flexible about the tools to read the file with then tidyverse is a really useful library to work with:

```
install.packages('tidyverse')
library('tidyverse')

read_fwf(file=fixedFileName, col_positions=fwf_widths(c(32,3,5,15,rep(1, 225)), 
    col_names = c("ID", "Gender", "Score", "Department", VNames)), col_types = NULL,
    trim_ws = TRUE)
```

if you need help with any of the docs just do

```
?tidyverse
?read_fwf
?fwf_widths
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

the col.names argument needs a vector of names to work, you've not put them in a vector.

Try this:

```
CombMatrix <- read.fwf(
   file = fixedFileName,
   width=c(32,3,5,15,rep(1, 225)),
   col.names = c("ID", "Gender", "Score", "Department", VNames),
   na.string="",
   fill=TRUE,
   strip.white=TRUE)
```